# C++ - how to structure a compositional hierarchy of types for scalability?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, composition, template-templates

I have three classes that can be combined statically. The lowest-level class is `A` and is a template class with a single parameter. This could be, say, an int. Then I have a higher-level class, `B`, which is dependent on the type `T` and `A`. Lastly, I have a higher-still class `C` which is dependent on `T`, `A` and `B`.

I can see two ways to code these relationships, either using template templates or public-scoped typedefs:

```
// template-template style:
template <typename T>
struct A {
  T at_;
};

template <typename T,
          template <typename> class A>
struct B {
  A<T> ba_;
  T bt_;
};

template <typename T,
          template <typename> class A,
          template <typename, template <typename> class> class B>
struct C {
  B<T, A> cb_;
  A<T> ca_;
  T ct_;
};


// public-scoped typedef style:
template <typename T>
struct A2 {
  typedef T TType;
  T at_;
};

template <class A>
struct B2 {
  typedef A AType;
  AType ba_;
  typename A::TType bt_;
};

template <class B>
struct C2 {
  typedef B BType;
  B cb_;
  typename B::AType ca_;
  typename B::AType::TType ct_;
};

// ...
// client code:
A<int> MyA;
B<int, A> MyB;
C<int, A, B> MyC;

A2<int> myA2;
B2<A2<int> > myB2;
C2<B2<A2<int> > > myC2;
```

Now consider a new class D that extends the pattern - with the first approach, the template declaration becomes almost completely unmanageable:

```
// horrendous to define:
template <typename T,
          template <typename> class A,
          template <typename,
                    template <typename> class> class B,
          template <typename,
                    template <typename> class,
                    template <typename, template <typename> class> class> class C>
struct D {
  C<T, A, B> dc_;
  B<T, A> db_;
  A<T> da_;
  T dt_;
};

// but nice to instantiate:
D<int, A, B, C> MyD;
```

The advantage of the first approach is that each participating class does not need to make provisions for higher-level classes. They do not need to be aware that they are part of a hierarchy so it's possible to reuse existing classes without changing them. This feels scalable in theory, but the class declaration syntax quickly becomes practically impossible to deal with without resorting to horrible preprocessor macros.

Alternatively:

```
template <class C>
struct D2 {
  typedef C CType;  // <-- not required right now, but better put it in just-in-case...
  C dc_;
  typename C::BType db_;
  typename C::BType::AType da_;
  typename C::BType::AType::TType ct_;
};
```

This second approach is much more concise, however it requires that participants of the hierarchy make their template parameters available as public typedef'd types. They need to cooperate at this compile-time interface so that they can communicate lower-level types up to higher levels. This requires widespread changes if they become part of such a hierarchy at a later date. This would seem to imply that it may be best to make **all** template parameters in **all** template classes available as public-scoped typedefs *just in case* they end up being used in this sort of hierarchy. This doesn't feel very scalable to me, but I have seen something similar in the Standard Library where the template parameter `value_type` is often provided.

My questions are - what other pros/cons of each approach have I missed, and which approach is likely to work best when creating a *growing* library of classes that tend to be combined statically like this? Is one style more widely accepted than the other? Are there alternatives not considered here?

A note about practical applications - I have a real-world application of this already, which involves special types of numerical values that behave in certain ways. These values are wrapped in higher-level classes that each provide a layer of extra functionality - one per layer. For example, one layer provides a callback mechanism, another provides caching, another provides value validation, another provides a transforming function. Higher layers may need to know about more than the layer directly beneath, hence the need for knowledge of types used to compose lower types. There are several different implementations at each level, hence the need to specify so many types. Various sections of this hierarchy can be used in other code, and in turn that code may find itself part of the hierarchy too. It's a fairly classic "composition" model that builds up functionality by composing lower-level classes, but created statically.

Comment: How about using an undefined variadic base, say `template <typename... Ts> class Base;` and specializing the ones that you care about? For example, you would have a specialization `template <typename T> class Base<T, A<T>, B<T,A<T>>{//Appropriate typedefs};`

Comment: @Pradhan interesting idea - I had wondered if variadic templates might help, but wasn't sure how they would be used. Would you be able to provide a more complete example as an answer, please?